# professional quality flex datagrid with pagination, CRUD, etc

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, datagrid

need high quality datagrid with:

- pagination
- CRUD - adding/deleting/updating rows by users
- other nice options such as filters, optionmenu, toolbar, etc.

there seems to be several very good options in Javascript (Ext-jS, several Jquery plugins/widgets (JQGrid, Datatables, at least 6 more good open source components...) which are very well designed,  implemented, documented and professional grade (and free).

however, everything i've seen to add above features to flex/AS seem to be hacks...
(there is one solution - flexicious - it isn't anywhere as good as some of the Javascript datagrids - not free either)

can someone point me to any good solutions in Flex/AS (like Javascript Datatables or JQGrid) ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the world for free (AKA: Well designed, implemented, documented, and professional grade).  Why would anyone go through that trouble when Adobe provides one in the Flex Framework?

Have you looked at the Flex DataGrid?  How about the Advanced DataGrid?  Those are your only two free options.

Pagination is a bit tricky.  It depends what you actually need.  If you tie it to a backend service such as LiveCycle or dbHibernate, then I understand the Flex DataGrid will do "Lazy Loading" which, basically, loads up the data as the user scrolls.  To me that is good user experience for pagination.  However, if you want a row of numbers, similar to what you might find on a traditional web page, you'd be stuck implementing that yourself.

Updating rows is supported through the use of itemEditors.  Deleting rows can be done very easily.  Creating rows is a bit more complex if you want to do it "in the grid" otherwise it's just a form you have to create.

Filters (and sorting) are almost trivial if you use a collection class as your dataProvider.

I'm not sure what you want in an option menu or a toolbar, but you can create a context menu in an itemRenderer with Flex for an option menu.  And you can tie a menu control to the DataGrid.

You mentioned Flexicious, which is a commercial option.

Have you checked out [ElfGrid](http://www.elfgrid.com/), which is also a commercial option.